# Google chrome Extension Native Messaging host written in C# is not run at computer startup

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have developed a Google chrome Extension that uses Native Messaging communication.

Well... extension works perfectly, but the problem is that Native Messaging host is not launched at computer startup. To launch it, I have to open chrome, list extensions, find my extension and then disable and re-enable it.

One thing I have realized of. is that when I disable and re-enable the extension and see task manager, I could see that 3 processes started running: chrome.exe, cmd and my native messaging host exe.

Maybe all 3 processes are not launched at startup because of the "cmd" command?

Why the cmd command is launched together with the native messaging host exe? How can I avoid it?

EDIT:

This is the manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Busca Cliente Lipigas",
  "short_name": "Busca Cliente",
  "description": "Permite recibir un número de teléfono desde SoftPhone y realizar la búsqueda del cliente en la página Web de Lipigas.",
  "version": "1.1",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],

  "icons" : { "16": "img/icon16.png",
              "48": "img/icon48.png",
              "128": "img/icon128.png" },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"],
    "persistent": false
    }

}
```

EDIT:

This is the background page:

```
var clientSearchPage;
var clientEditPage;
var executed;

//console.log('Extensión iniciada.');
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.desytec.lipigas.sll');

port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    //console.log("Se recibió el comando " + msg.command + ' con el parámetro ' + msg.parameter);

    port.postMessage({ status: processCommand(msg.command + ' ' + msg.parameter) });
});

chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function () {
    port.postMessage({ status: 'EXIT' });
})

function processCommand(cmd) {    
    var parts = cmd.split(/\s+/);
    try {
        switch (parts[0]) {
            case 'Phone':
                executed = false;
                setPhone(parts[1]);
                return '+OK-Phone';
            case 'SetClientSearchPage':
                clientSearchPage = parts[1];
                if (clientSearchPage[0] != '/')
                    clientSearchPage = '/' + clientSearchPage;
                //console.log('Se configuró la página de búsqueda del cliente ' + clientSearchPage);
                return '+OK-SetClientSearchPage';
            case 'SetClientEditPage':
                clientEditPage = parts[1];
                if (clientEditPage[0] != '/')
                    clientEditPage = '/' + clientEditPage;
                //console.log('Se configuró la página de edición del cliente ' + clientEditPage);
                return '+OK-SetClientEditPage';
            default:
                return '+ERR-Comando No Encontrado';
        }
        //tcpConnection.sendMessage(Commands.run(cmd[0], cmd.slice(1)));
    } catch (ex) {
        return '+ERR-Comando No Procesado'
    }
}

function setPhone(phone) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
    }, function (tabs) {
        var tab = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            var tabURL = tabs[i].url;
            if (tabURL.indexOf(clientSearchPage) != -1 || tabURL.indexOf(clientEditPage) != -1)
                tab = tabs[i];
            //console.log(tabURL);
        }

        if (!executed) {
            searchClient(tab, phone);
            executed = true;
        }
    });
}

function searchClient(tab, phone) {
    if (tab == null)
        console.log('No se encontró ninguna de las páginas del cliente: ' + clientSearchPage + ', ' + clientEditPage);
    else {
        var site = '';
        var url = tab.url;
        if (url.indexOf(clientEditPage) != -1)
            site = url.substr(0, url.indexOf(clientEditPage));
        else if (url.indexOf(clientSearchPage) != -1)
            site = url.substr(0, url.indexOf(clientSearchPage));

        //console.log(site + clientSearchPage + '?telefono=' + phone);

        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true, url: site + clientSearchPage + '?telefono=' + phone });

        //console.log('Se actualizó la URL con: ' + site + clientSearchPage + '?telefono=' + phone);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Since the native messaging host is started only by `chrome.runtime.connectNative` as per [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), you need to start your extension at the computer startup by specifying the [`"background"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#background) in your extension's manifest.json:

   ```
   "permissions": ["background", "nativeMessaging"],
   ```

   > When any installed hosted app, packaged app, or extension has "background" permission, Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome. The "background" permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome.

   This behavior can be disabled by a user in Chrome's settings:
   `[x] Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed` option.
2. `cmd` is launched to create the stdio pipeline. On Windows the command line is:

   > C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c YOURHOSTAPP.exe --parent-window=10158736 chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/ < \.\pipe\chrome.nativeMessaging.in.9c12d69ad9deb1ce > \.\pipe\chrome.nativeMessaging.out.9c12d69ad9deb1ce

   [As of Oct 5, 2016](https://codereview.chromium.org/2271143002/) `--parent-window=` parameter will be moved after `chrome-extension://`.

Comment: I have updated the question with the manifest file. It is the way you show. However, as I told, the native messaging host is launched when I manually disable and then re-enable the extension... so I think the json file is correct. And even, when I close Chrome, the native mesaging host continues running. The problem happens only at computer startup (native messaging host is not automacally started)

Comment: @jstuardo You should show how you call `connectNative`.

Comment: I have added the background page in the question. connectNative appears at the beginning, and this is: var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.desytec.lipigas.sll');...... at computer startup, the extension appears enabled so, I think it passes through background page.... maybe in some part of that code there is an error that causes the native messaging host not to be launched

Comment: @jstuardo, try `"persistent": true`. Also, you can view the errors if `Collect errors` checkbox is enabled for your extension on chrome://extensions page

Comment: @wOxxOm where is that checkbox? I loaded extensions page but I did not see anything like that.

Comment: @wOxxOm This checkbox isn't available in stable builds.

Comment: I know, however, if the problem is that the native messaging host applicaion is not executed, so the problem should be on chrome.runtime.connectNative call. As I told in the question, the host application is not run only at computer startup (when I disable and then reenable the extension, the host application is correctly run) so it is useless to use devide & conquer since I know where the problem is. The fact is that I don't need to know where is the problem but what is the actual error that occurs. How can I log the actual error occured? nothing is shown in console output of the extension.

Comment: I was investigating about it and I have found that I can call chrome.storage.local.set({ 'key': value }); and add the storage permission in the manifest. Is that simple? however, if I need to catch the error, can I use try catch block to try to log the possible error? Google chrome documentation does not mention about exception throwing when the call fails

Comment: In addition to `"persistent": true` suggestion, try [onStartup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup) event.

Comment: I tried to log everything in the extension using local storage, but local storage is not persistent. I cannot see all data I have added to the storage... I only can see the current data.

Comment: Both chrome.storage.local and `localStorage` are persistent by design. As for onStartup event, the obvious candidates would be 1) logging 2) connectNative